# MongoDB - making db.fsyncUnlock(); work

Tags: bash, mongodb, backup, database

I have a shell script that backs up MongoDB database.

I have to lock the database before backing it up.

`mongo --eval "db.fsyncLock();"` works fine, but when I run `mongo --eval "db.fsyncUnlock();"` it just waits and does nothing.

How can I make unlocking work?

edit: I know I have to keep the connection open, but how?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/backups-and-locking ?

Comment: Thank you, this example really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Executing MongoDB commands from Bash didn't really work, because you have to keep the connection open if you want to unlock the database again.
But when executing commands from Bash it connects to the database, executes the command and disconnects.

I ended up making a Javascript script and executing it from the Mongo Shell.